# how to disable build in Jenkins master

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ecs, jenkins-agent

I have setup Jenkins slave in AWS ECS, when jenkins have a build job, it will start a container in ECS instance, when the build job completed, the container will be gone. I want to disable build in Jenkins master to force user build in slave.
I tried to set "# of executors"=0 in Configure System, but all the build job pending, it not go to slave to build. do you have a idea about this?
Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946929/ci-with-jenkins-how-to-force-building-happen-on-slaves-instead-of-master

Comment: Besides the previous comment, you probably have to instruct your job to use the AWS ECS slave or mark the AWS ECS slave as utilize this slave as much as possible.

Comment: I read this topic, they advise check "Restrict where this project can be run" and specific slave node, but how to force user check this checkbox, if they do not check, it will build in master.

Answer (score 1):

When you check "Restrict where this project can be run" and text your slave's lable, your Job can only be run by that node.